# Unable to Get Kernel Crash Dump on Kernel Panic

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-panic, arm64, kexec, kdump

I'm using kexec-tools to get a crash dump of kernel on kernel panic. However, when I trigger the panic using sysrq-trigger, the system freezes. I have to power off and then power on to restore the system. There is no automatic reboot and no crash dump is available in /var/crash.
The following are the configurations and details:

- Linux Distro - Debian Buster arm64
- Linux Kernel - 4.19.35
- kexec-tools v2.0.22 (Built from source)
- All Kernel Configs specifed here for arm64 enabled: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kdump/kdump.txt

Both the main kernel and crash kernel are exactly the same. (Although using uncompressed Image as crash kernel)
`/proc/cmdline = crashkernel=512M nokaslr # Along with other arguments`
The crash kernel space gets reserved (verified by dmesg)

Loading crashkernel to kick-in on a kernel panic:
`$ sudo kexec -p ./Image --append=" root=/dev/sda1 console=same_as_main_kernel earlycon=same_as_main_kernel rootwait rw 1 max_cpus=1 reset_devices`

The root fs is same as that used for main kernel.

Trigerring Kernel Panic:
`$ echo c | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-triggger`

The serial console freezes with standard kernel panic stacktrace. One of the logs specific to Kdump is:
`[14645.1099571] CPU: 2 PID: 20518 Comm: tee Kdump: loaded Not tainted 4.19.35-g9e41bb234b42 #2`

The system however does not reboot.

One thing to note is that I can boot into the crash kernel if I want to explicitly:

`$ sudo kexec -l ./Image --append=" root=/dev/sda1 console=same_as_main_kernel earlycon=same_as_main_kernel rootwait rw 1 max_cpus=1 reset_devices`

`$ sudo kexec -e`

This boots into the specified kernel.

How can I resolve/debug this issue further in which the crash kernel does not seem to kick-in in the event of a kernel panic.

Comment: I have the exact same situation on Debian testing, with kernel `5.16.0-6-amd64`. Did you manage to find a solution eventually?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be explained with QEMU.

Running the Ubuntu 22.04 in QEMU

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ./ubuntu.qcow2 -enable-kvm -m 8G -smp 8 -serial stdio
```

Edit the Ubuntu 22.04's grub, remove the kernel option [`quiet`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-the-nomodeset-quiet-and-splash-kernel-parameters-mean) so we can get the debug message.

The following is `kexec -e` log:

```
;-1f[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Reboot with kexec Screen.
plymouth-kexec.service
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Execute the k…c -e command to reboot system.
[  OK  ] Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
         Stopping Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer...
         Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
// -------------- and  many similar entries -----------------------
// -------------- and  many similar entries -----------------------
    // many similar entries
[  OK  ] Reached target System Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
         Starting Reboot via kexec...
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.0-25-generic (buildd@ubuntu) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils fo
```

and this is the kernel panic's log:

```
martins3-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 login: [  280.288704] sysrq: Trigger a crash
[  280.290141] Kernel panic - not syncing: sysrq triggered crash
[  280.292990] CPU: 6 PID: 2539 Comm: tee Kdump: loaded Not tainted 5.15.0-25-generic #25-Ubuntu
[  280.296366] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.16.0-0-gd239552ce722-prebuilt.qemu.org 04/04
[  280.298395] Call Trace:
[  280.298847]  <TASK>
[  280.299243]  show_stack+0x52/0x58
[  280.299964]  dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x5f
[  280.300862]  dump_stack+0x10/0x12
[  280.301584]  panic+0x149/0x321
[  280.302254]  sysrq_handle_crash+0x1a/0x20
[  280.303120]  __handle_sysrq.cold+0xcc/0x1a2
[  280.304095]  ? apparmor_file_permission+0x70/0x160
[  280.305121]  write_sysrq_trigger+0x28/0x40
[  280.306007]  proc_reg_write+0x5a/0x9
[  280.306802]  ? __cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[  280.307604]  vfs_write+0xc3/0x260
[  280.308316]  ksys_write+0x67/0xe0
[  280.309014]  __x64_sys_write+0x19/0x20
[  280.309798]  do_syscall_64+0x5c/0xc0
[  280.311102]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
[  280.312097]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
[  280.313089]  ? __x64_sys_write+0x19/0x20
[  280.313905]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
[  280.314684]  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
[  280.315705]  ? irqentry_exit+0x19/0x30
[  280.316524]  ? exc_page_fault+0x89/0x160
[  280.317322]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
[  280.318153]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
[  280.319162] RIP: 0033:0x7f39a4c57a37
[  280.319864] Code: 10 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b7 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 14
[  280.323539] RSP: 002b:00007ffd893cb268 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
[  280.325084] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 00007f39a4c57a37
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.0-25-generic (buildd@ubuntu) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils f)
// ---------------- kernel boot messages -----------------------
// ---------------- kernel boot messages -----------------------
[    0.610479] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.611162] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.611738] VFIO - User Level meta-driver version: 0.3
[    0.613621] kthreadd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xcc0(GFP_KERNEL), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[    0.614698] CPU: 0 PID: 93 Comm: kthreadd Not tainted 5.15.0-25-generic #25-Ubuntu
```

So the difference is clear, `kexec -e` is a wrapper of [reboot](https://github.com/horms/kexec-tools/blob/bfab31851465cb18f3dd75371e7f04a4bc6ad83c/kexec/kexec.c#L927) syscall. `kexec -e` and kernel panic only shares similar but **not the same** code path, because the kernel can't guarantee too much in panic mode.
Kernel panic fails to boot due to lack of memory, so the machine freezes.

So how to fix the problem? Edit your `/boot/grub/grub.conf`, increase the kernel's parameter `crashkernel` and reboot.